# get error messages in content area on cart page Magento

Tags: magento, content-management-system, global, message

HI i have made a module in which i have a controller which adds product to the cart through url . I have add a error messages from controller if the product is not valid.

The problem is the error message is shown above the content area .I need to show those in the content area.I have also tried to add these blocks in

> checkout.xml in content area

```
         <reference name="content">
            <block type="checkout/cart" name="checkout.cart">
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
            <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
```

but still it not loads the messages in the content area and show above the content area. Can you please suggest me how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to generate these errors - default magento handlers? they generate errors just above the breadcrumb area.

One option would be to give it a id/class and manipulate through javascript.
OR,
Generate custom errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can either unset/re-add blocks as needed with the following methods:

```
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>global_notices</name></action>
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>global_messages</name></action>
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>messages</name></action>


    <block type="page/html_notices" name="global_notices" as="global_notices" template="page/html/notices.phtml" />
    <block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>
    <block type="core/messages" name="messages" as="messages"/>
```

If adding these as needed using template hints to confirm does not work, find the following line in

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\cart.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?>
```

And comment it out/move it to where you wish to render it.